# I want replace single quotes with double quotes in a list

Tags: python, string, list, multidimensional-array, items

i need convert list items ' convert "

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print(thislist)
```

result

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

i want this

```
["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```

but the variable must be a list, not a string.

Comment: Those are functionally identical. Why do you want double quotes? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok two things. The variable will have double quotes. The output will have single. Do you want to have the output to contain double quotes?

Comment: No matter what quotes you use, Python will print them with single quotes, there's no use trying to print them differently, they're equivalent. Unless you want to go to the trouble of treating a list as a string and replacing the quotes to suit your requirement, but I'd really advice against that.

Answer (score 0):

A string as a sequence of characters not intended to have numeric value. In Python, such sequence of characters is included inside single or double quotes.

As far as language syntax is concerned, there is no difference in single or double quoted string. Both representations can be used interchangeably.

However, if either single or double quote is a part of the string itself, then the string must be placed in double or single quotes respectively.

```
str1='Hello "Python"'
```

equivalent to

```
Str2="Hello 'Python'"
```

Comment: `keys = [k.strip() for k in keywords.lower().split(",")]`

Comment: `"keywords": keys` result `'keywords': ['prayer', 'pray']'`

Comment: this would split based on `,`. what exactly is the problem ?Why you want double quotes ?

Comment: I'm sending post data 'prayer' does not happen. It should be "prayer". otherwise post data gives an error.

Comment: This is the post data that should go. however, I am sending it with single quotes. and this is happening  https://i.imgur.com/NvcCfRC.png

Comment: @bymechul just try doing `str(data)` before sending the post query

Comment: `keywords': "['italian', 'logo', 'gangster', 'man', 'mafia', 'godfather', 'black', 'avatar', 'mascot', 'vector', 'hat', 'outline', 'italy', 'suit', 'men', 'vintage', 'portrait', 'chicago', 'art', 'silhouette', 'boss', 'flat', 'male', 'cartoon', 'people', 'illustration', 'person', 'gang', 'gentleman', 'icon', 'mustache', 'design', 'mafioso', 'graphic', 'character', 'isolated', 'head', 'background', 'symbol', 'human', 'sign', 'face', 'white', 'fashion', 'retro', 'criminal', 'style', 'crime', 'killer', 'business']"`

Comment: "[ and 'italian' It gives an error because of these

Comment: `keywords": ["italian", "logo", "gangster", "man", "mafia", "godfather", "black", "avatar", "mascot", "vector", "hat", "outline", "italy", "suit", "men", "vintage", "portrait", "chicago", "art", "silhouette", "boss", "flat", "male", "cartoon", "people", "illustration", "person", "gang", "gentleman", "icon", "mustache", "design", "mafioso", "graphic", "character", "isolated", "head", "background", "symbol", "human", "sign", "face", "white", "fashion", "retro", "criminal", "style", "crime", "killer", "business"]`  this is what should be

Comment: @bymechul from what I understand , you are inserting into a string rather than a list. It would be really helpful if you can add some code which you have used before `post` query

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/bTJUQGn.png It takes the keywords from the text file.

Comment: @bymechul remove str(keys)

Comment: single quotation marks are incorrect. double quotation mark is true